# does $\|A\| > \|B\|$, $A$ and $B$ matrices, imply that $\|Ax\| >\|Bx\|$ for all $x$ in some vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm wondering if I can prove the first inequality in a question that I am working on, does that make the second inequality automatic?

Thanks,

Comment: It only implies  $\|Bx\|<\|A\|\>\|x\|$ for all $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, remind that all vector spaces include $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the answer to the question in your question *title* is "yes" if you replace the strict inequality $>$ by weak inequality $\ge$. There will always be at least a one-dimensional subspace of the whole vector space in which the inequality is true. But the answer for the question about whether it's true for the *whole* space is of course "no" if the space has dimension greater than 1. But the one-dimensional case is probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This system produces a counterexample.

\begin{bmatrix} 
\ 1 & 0
\\0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}
Determinant of this is 1

\begin{bmatrix} 
\ 10 & 0
\\0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
Determinant of this is zero, less than the first matrix

\begin{bmatrix} 
\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Each of the multiplications of the matrices by this vector are 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
and
\begin{bmatrix} 
\ 10 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
Respectively.
The length of each of these vectors is 1 and 10 respectively. The second matrix multiplication being the larger of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean $||A||$ to be the norm of the operator $A$. Also, you probably mean $\ge $ rather then $>$. The answer is still No.

Consider the operators $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right )$ and $B = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{array} \right )$.